# Using $ variables in preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, variables, preg-replace

Ummm... how do I use variables in a call to preg_replace?

This didn't work:

```
foreach($numarray as $num => $text)
    {
        $patterns[] = '/<ces>(.*?)\+$num(.*?)<\/ces>/';
        $replacements[] = '<ces>$1<$text/>$2</ces>';
    }
```

Yes, the `$num` is preceeded by a plus sign. Yes, I want to "`tag the $num as <$text/>`".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your replacement pattern looks ok, but as you've used single quotes in the matching pattern, your $num variable won't be inserted into it. Instead, try

```
$patterns[] = '/<ces>(.*?)\+'.$num.'(.*?)<\/ces>/';
$replacements[] = '<ces>$1<'.$text.'/>$2</ces>';
```

Also note that when building up a pattern from "unknown" inputs like this, it's usually a good idea to use [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote). e.g.

```
$patterns[] = '/<ces>(.*?)\+'.preg_quote($num).'(.*?)<\/ces>/';
```

Though I guess given the variable name it's always numeric in your case.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, Paul - both your inputs helped!

Answer (score 14):

Variables will only be expanded in [strings declared with double quotes](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). So either use double quotes:

```
$patterns[]     = "/<ces>(.*?)\\+$num(.*?)<\\/ces>/";
$replacements[] = "<ces>$1<$text/>$2</ces>";
```

Or use string concatenation:

```
$patterns[]     = '/<ces>(.*?)\+'.$num.'(.*?)<\/ces>/';
$replacements[] = '<ces>$1<'.$text.'/>$2</ces>';
```

You should also take a look at [`preg_quote`](http://docs.php.net/preg_quote) if your variables may contain regular expression meta characters.