# How to use variables in the regex of preg_replace?

Tags: php

I have code like below:

```
    $titles=$key->post_title;//$titles just contain some strings.
    $replace='<a target="_blank" href="http://wiki:8888/wiki/'.$titles.'">'.$titles.'</a>';
    //this is want I want to do ,use $titles in the regex.
    $regex = '/'.$titles.'/';
    $content = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $content, 1);
```

So I want to use $titles in the regex,but it's not working.It gave me a warning like :

> preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '>' in line ~~~

I also tried:

```
$regex = "/".$titles."/";
```

or:

```
$regex = "/$titles/";
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: And if you'd put a simple string instead of the variable the warning will disappear? Maybe consider using preg_quote (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400768/using-variables-in-preg-replace-in-php)

Comment: Yes,when I use string like $regex = "/titles/"; ,it works fine ,but need to use variable.